Dependecy problems when using `mkdocs`. Cannot import `AstRenderer` form `mistune`
I am having a problem using mkdocs.
I have set up a conda environment with Python version 3.12.
For the project I am working on I installed all the packages I need and want to use mkdcos.
There is already a mkdcos.yml. When I run mkdocs build I get the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "$path/anaconda3/envs/pyeed_niklas/lib/python3.12/site-packages/nbconvert/filters/markdown_mistune.py", line 25, in <module>
    from mistune import (  # type:ignore[attr-defined]
  File "$path/anaconda3/envs/pyeed_niklas/lib/python3.12/site-packages/mistune/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .renderers import AstRenderer, HTMLRenderer
ImportError: cannot import name 'AstRenderer' from 'mistune.renderers' ($path/anaconda3/envs/pyeed_niklas/lib/python3.12/site-packages/mistune/renderers/__init__.py)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "$path/anaconda3/envs/pyeed_niklas/bin/mkdocs", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
             ^^^^^
  File "$path/anaconda3/envs/pyeed_niklas/lib/python3.12/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1157, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "$path/anaconda3/envs/pyeed_niklas/lib/python3.12/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1078, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "$path/anaconda3/envs/pyeed_niklas/lib/python3.12/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1688, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "$path/anaconda3/envs/pyeed_niklas/lib/python3.12/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1434, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "$path/anaconda3/envs/pyeed_niklas/lib/python3.12/site-packages/click/core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "$path/anaconda3/envs/pyeed_niklas/lib/python3.12/site-packages/mkdocs/__main__.py", line 281, in build_command
    cfg = config.load_config(**kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "$path/anaconda3/envs/pyeed_niklas/lib/python3.12/site-packages/mkdocs/config/base.py", line 374, in load_config
    errors, warnings = cfg.validate()
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "$path/anaconda3/envs/pyeed_niklas/lib/python3.12/site-packages/mkdocs/config/base.py", line 231, in validate
    run_failed, run_warnings = self._validate()
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "$path/anaconda3/envs/pyeed_niklas/lib/python3.12/site-packages/mkdocs/config/base.py", line 188, in _validate
    self[key] = config_option.validate(value)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "$path/anaconda3/envs/pyeed_niklas/lib/python3.12/site-packages/mkdocs/config/config_options.py", line 186, in validate
    return self.run_validation(value)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "$path/anaconda3/envs/pyeed_niklas/lib/python3.12/site-packages/mkdocs/config/config_options.py", line 1075, in run_validation
    self.load_plugin_with_namespace(name, cfg)
  File "$path/anaconda3/envs/pyeed_niklas/lib/python3.12/site-packages/mkdocs/config/config_options.py", line 1113, in load_plugin_with_namespace
    return (name, self.load_plugin(name, config))
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "$path/anaconda3/envs/pyeed_niklas/lib/python3.12/site-packages/mkdocs/config/config_options.py", line 1131, in load_plugin
    plugin_cls = self.installed_plugins[name].load()
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "$path/anaconda3/envs/pyeed_niklas/lib/python3.12/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 205, in load
    module = import_module(match.group('module'))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "$path/anaconda3/envs/pyeed_niklas/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "$path/anaconda3/envs/pyeed_niklas/lib/python3.12/site-packages/mkdocs_jupyter/plugin.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import convert
  File "$path/anaconda3/envs/pyeed_niklas/lib/python3.12/site-packages/mkdocs_jupyter/convert.py", line 1, in <module>
    from nbconvert.filters.markdown_mistune import IPythonRenderer
  File "$path/anaconda3/envs/pyeed_niklas/lib/python3.12/site-packages/nbconvert/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .exporters import (
  File "$path/anaconda3/envs/pyeed_niklas/lib/python3.12/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .html import HTMLExporter
  File "$path/anaconda3/envs/pyeed_niklas/lib/python3.12/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/html.py", line 29, in <module>
    from nbconvert.filters.markdown_mistune import IPythonRenderer, MarkdownWithMath
  File "$path/anaconda3/envs/pyeed_niklas/lib/python3.12/site-packages/nbconvert/filters/markdown_mistune.py", line 40, in <module>
    from mistune import (  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
  File "$path/anaconda3/envs/pyeed_niklas/lib/python3.12/site-packages/mistune/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .renderers import AstRenderer, HTMLRenderer
ImportError: cannot import name 'AstRenderer' from 'mistune.renderers' ($path/anaconda3/envs/pyeed_niklas/lib/python3.12/site-packages/mistune/renderers/__init__.py)

Now I tried everything in order to resolve this problem:
I did conda install mistune
I did conda update mistune
The current version of the packages is:
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                        main  
_openmp_mutex             5.1                       1_gnu  
aiometer                  0.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
annotated-types           0.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
anyio                     4.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
anytree                   2.12.1                   pypi_0    pypi
argon2-cffi               23.1.0                   pypi_0    pypi
argon2-cffi-bindings      21.2.0          py312h5eee18b_0  
arrow                     1.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
astropy                   6.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
astropy-iers-data         0.2024.7.22.0.34.13          pypi_0    pypi
asttokens                 2.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
async-lru                 2.0.4           py312h06a4308_0  
attrs                     23.2.0                   pypi_0    pypi
autoflake                 2.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
babel                     2.15.0                   pypi_0    pypi
backoff                   2.2.1                    pypi_0    pypi
beautifulsoup4            4.12.3          py312h06a4308_0  
bigtree                   0.17.2                   pypi_0    pypi
biopython                 1.84                     pypi_0    pypi
black                     23.12.1                  pypi_0    pypi
blas                      1.0                         mkl  
bleach                    6.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
brotli-python             1.0.9           py312h6a678d5_8  
build                     1.2.1                    pypi_0    pypi
bzip2                     1.0.8                h5eee18b_6  
ca-certificates           2024.7.2             h06a4308_0  
cachecontrol              0.14.0                   pypi_0    pypi
certifi                   2024.7.4        py312h06a4308_0  
cffi                      1.16.0          py312h5eee18b_1  
chardet                   5.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
charset-normalizer        3.3.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
cleo                      2.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
click                     8.1.7                    pypi_0    pypi
colorama                  0.4.6                    pypi_0    pypi
colorbrewer               0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
colour                    0.1.5                    pypi_0    pypi
comm                      0.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
contourpy                 1.2.1                    pypi_0    pypi
crashtest                 0.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
cryptography              43.0.0                   pypi_0    pypi
cycler                    0.12.1                   pypi_0    pypi
debugpy                   1.8.2                    pypi_0    pypi
decorator                 5.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
defusedxml                0.7.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
distlib                   0.3.8                    pypi_0    pypi
dnspython                 2.6.1                    pypi_0    pypi
dotted-dict               1.1.3                    pypi_0    pypi
dulwich                   0.21.7                   pypi_0    pypi
email-validator           2.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
executing                 2.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
expat                     2.6.2                h6a678d5_0  
fastjsonschema            2.20.0                   pypi_0    pypi
filelock                  3.15.4                   pypi_0    pypi
fonttools                 4.53.1                   pypi_0    pypi
fqdn                      1.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
ghp-import                2.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
gitdb                     4.0.11                   pypi_0    pypi
gitpython                 3.1.43                   pypi_0    pypi
h11                       0.14.0                   pypi_0    pypi
httpcore                  1.0.5                    pypi_0    pypi
httpx                     0.27.0                   pypi_0    pypi
idna                      3.7             py312h06a4308_0  
igraph                    0.11.6                   pypi_0    pypi
iniconfig                 2.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
installer                 0.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
intel-openmp              2023.1.0         hdb19cb5_46306  
ipykernel                 6.29.5                   pypi_0    pypi
ipython                   8.26.0                   pypi_0    pypi
ipython-genutils          0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
isoduration               20.11.0                  pypi_0    pypi
jaraco-classes            3.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jedi                      0.19.1          py312h06a4308_0  
jeepney                   0.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jinja2                    3.1.4           py312h06a4308_0  
joblib                    1.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
json5                     0.9.25                   pypi_0    pypi
jsonpointer               3.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jsonschema                4.23.0                   pypi_0    pypi
jsonschema-specifications 2023.12.1                pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-client            8.6.2                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-contrib-core      0.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-contrib-nbextensions 0.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-highlight-selected-word 0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-lsp               2.2.5                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-nbextensions-configurator 0.6.4                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-server            2.14.2                   pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-server-terminals  0.5.3                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter_client            8.6.0           py312h06a4308_0  
jupyter_core              5.7.2           py312h06a4308_0  
jupyter_events            0.10.0          py312h06a4308_0  
jupyter_server            2.14.1          py312h06a4308_0  
jupyter_server_terminals  0.4.4           py312h06a4308_1  
jupyterlab                4.2.4                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyterlab-pygments       0.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyterlab-server         2.27.3                   pypi_0    pypi
jupyterlab_pygments       0.1.2                      py_0  
jupyterlab_server         2.25.1          py312h06a4308_0  
jupytext                  1.16.3                   pypi_0    pypi
keyring                   24.3.1                   pypi_0    pypi
kiwisolver                1.4.5                    pypi_0    pypi
ld_impl_linux-64          2.38                 h1181459_1  
libffi                    3.4.4                h6a678d5_1  
libgcc-ng                 11.2.0               h1234567_1  
libgomp                   11.2.0               h1234567_1  
libsodium                 1.0.18               h7b6447c_0  
libstdcxx-ng              11.2.0               h1234567_1  
libuuid                   1.41.5               h5eee18b_0  
lxml                      5.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
markdown                  3.6                      pypi_0    pypi
markdown-it-py            3.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
markupsafe                2.1.5                    pypi_0    pypi
matplotlib                3.9.1                    pypi_0    pypi
matplotlib-inline         0.1.7                    pypi_0    pypi
mdit-py-plugins           0.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
mdurl                     0.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
mergedeep                 1.3.4                    pypi_0    pypi
mistune                   3.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
mkdocs                    1.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
mkdocs-get-deps           0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
mkdocs-jupyter            0.24.8                   pypi_0    pypi
mkdocs-material           9.5.30                   pypi_0    pypi
mkdocs-material-extensions 1.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
mkl                       2023.1.0         h213fc3f_46344  
mkl-service               2.4.0           py312h5eee18b_1  
mkl_fft                   1.3.8           py312h5eee18b_0  
mkl_random                1.2.4           py312hdb19cb5_0  
more-itertools            10.3.0                   pypi_0    pypi
msgpack                   1.0.8                    pypi_0    pypi
mypy-extensions           1.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
nbclient                  0.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
nbconvert                 7.16.4                   pypi_0    pypi
nbformat                  5.10.4                   pypi_0    pypi
ncurses                   6.4                  h6a678d5_0  
neo4j                     5.22.0                   pypi_0    pypi
nest-asyncio              1.6.0           py312h06a4308_0  
networkx                  3.3                      pypi_0    pypi
nob                       0.8.2                    pypi_0    pypi
notebook                  7.2.1                    pypi_0    pypi
notebook-shim             0.2.4                    pypi_0    pypi
numpy                     1.26.4          py312hc5e2394_0  
numpy-base                1.26.4          py312h0da6c21_0  
openssl                   3.0.14               h5eee18b_0  
overrides                 7.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
packaging                 24.1            py312h06a4308_0  
paginate                  0.5.6                    pypi_0    pypi
pandas                    2.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
pandocfilters             1.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
parso                     0.8.4                    pypi_0    pypi
pathspec                  0.12.1                   pypi_0    pypi
pexpect                   4.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pillow                    10.4.0                   pypi_0    pypi
pip                       24.0            py312h06a4308_0  
pkginfo                   1.11.1                   pypi_0    pypi
platformdirs              4.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
plotly                    5.23.0                   pypi_0    pypi
pluggy                    1.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
poetry                    1.8.3                    pypi_0    pypi
poetry-core               1.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
poetry-plugin-export      1.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
prometheus-client         0.20.0                   pypi_0    pypi
prometheus_client         0.14.1          py312h06a4308_0  
prompt-toolkit            3.0.47                   pypi_0    pypi
prompt_toolkit            3.0.43               hd3eb1b0_0  
psutil                    5.9.8                    pypi_0    pypi
ptyprocess                0.7.0              pyhd3eb1b0_2  
pure-eval                 0.2.3                    pypi_0    pypi
pure_eval                 0.2.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
py4cytoscape              1.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pycparser                 2.22                     pypi_0    pypi
pydantic                  2.8.2                    pypi_0    pypi
pydantic-core             2.20.1                   pypi_0    pypi
pydantic-xml              2.11.0                   pypi_0    pypi
pyeed                     0.3.6                    pypi_0    pypi
pyerfa                    2.0.1.4                  pypi_0    pypi
pyflakes                  3.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pygments                  2.18.0                   pypi_0    pypi
pyhmmer                   0.10.14                  pypi_0    pypi
pymdown-extensions        10.9                     pypi_0    pypi
pymsaviz                  0.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
pyparsing                 3.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
pyproject-hooks           1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pysocks                   1.7.1           py312h06a4308_0  
pytest                    8.3.2                    pypi_0    pypi
pytest-mock               3.14.0                   pypi_0    pypi
python                    3.12.4               h5148396_1  
python-dateutil           2.9.0post0      py312h06a4308_2  
python-dotenv             1.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
python-fastjsonschema     2.16.2          py312h06a4308_0  
python-frontmatter        1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
python-json-logger        2.0.7           py312h06a4308_0  
pytz                      2024.1          py312h06a4308_0  
pyyaml                    6.0.1           py312h5eee18b_0  
pyyaml-env-tag            0.1                      pypi_0    pypi
pyzmq                     26.0.3                   pypi_0    pypi
rapidfuzz                 3.9.4                    pypi_0    pypi
readline                  8.2                  h5eee18b_0  
referencing               0.35.1                   pypi_0    pypi
regex                     2024.7.24                pypi_0    pypi
requests                  2.32.3          py312h06a4308_0  
requests-toolbelt         1.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
rfc3339-validator         0.1.4           py312h06a4308_0  
rfc3986-validator         0.1.1           py312h06a4308_0  
rich                      13.7.1                   pypi_0    pypi
rpds-py                   0.19.1                   pypi_0    pypi
ruff                      0.4.10                   pypi_0    pypi
scipy                     1.14.0                   pypi_0    pypi
sdrdm                     0.2.3                    pypi_0    pypi
secretstorage             3.3.3                    pypi_0    pypi
send2trash                1.8.3                    pypi_0    pypi
setuptools                71.1.0                   pypi_0    pypi
shellingham               1.5.4                    pypi_0    pypi
six                       1.16.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1  
smmap                     5.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
sniffio                   1.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
soupsieve                 2.5             py312h06a4308_0  
sqlite                    3.45.3               h5eee18b_0  
stack-data                0.6.3                    pypi_0    pypi
stack_data                0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
tbb                       2021.8.0             hdb19cb5_0  
tenacity                  8.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
terminado                 0.18.1                   pypi_0    pypi
texttable                 1.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tinycss2                  1.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tk                        8.6.14               h39e8969_0  
toml                      0.10.2                   pypi_0    pypi
tomlkit                   0.13.0                   pypi_0    pypi
tornado                   6.4.1           py312h5eee18b_0  
traitlets                 5.14.3          py312h06a4308_0  
trove-classifiers         2024.7.2                 pypi_0    pypi
typer                     0.9.4                    pypi_0    pypi
types-python-dateutil     2.9.0.20240316           pypi_0    pypi
typing-extensions         4.12.2                   pypi_0    pypi
typing_extensions         4.11.0          py312h06a4308_0  
tzdata                    2024.1                   pypi_0    pypi
uri-template              1.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
urllib3                   2.2.2           py312h06a4308_0  
validators                0.22.0                   pypi_0    pypi
virtualenv                20.26.3                  pypi_0    pypi
watchdog                  4.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
wcwidth                   0.2.13                   pypi_0    pypi
webcolors                 24.6.0                   pypi_0    pypi
webencodings              0.5.1           py312h06a4308_2  
websocket-client          1.8.0           py312h06a4308_0  
wheel                     0.43.0          py312h06a4308_0  
xz                        5.4.6                h5eee18b_1  
yaml                      0.2.5                h7b6447c_0  
zeromq                    4.3.5                h6a678d5_0  
zlib                      1.2.13               h5eee18b_1

Any help would be appreciated. I know it is a lot of messages with packages, but I would like you to have the full picture.

Since mkdocs and mistune are installed from PyPI, you should do python -m pip install -U mistune mkdocs

this comment helped
